# Can you explain this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

```
min(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: abs(a[i]-11.5))
```

i could not understand . please help me with it.

Comment: It's using `min`, `range`, `len`, `lambda` and `abs`. Do you already understand any of those, or are you asking for all of them to be explained? Or what part of their interaction has you confused?

Comment: using `min(range(len(a)), key = lambda i : a[i])` computes `argmin`, i.e. the index `i` that its value `a[i]` is the minimum. Here, the key is more complex and makes this function return the index `i` that its value `a[i]` is closest to `11.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python built-in [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) returns the minimum argument in some iterable. Since Python 2.5, however, it also takes a `key` argument, a function by which to evaluate elements in the iterable.

The argument you pass to `key` is how each element `x` in the collection is evaluated, as `argument(x)`. You pass a `lambda`, an anonymous function, that computes `lambda i: abs(a[i]-11.5)`, that is, for each index it takes the value in `a` at that index, and computes the absolute value of `a[i] - 11.5`. This works since you pass the indices of `a` to the `min` function, as `range(len(a))` is exactly that collection (it is the range from `0` to `len(a)`, in steps of `1`).

Taking all this together, what you get is the index of the element in `a` that is nearest to `11.5` in absolute distance.

Answer (score 0):

`min` returns the minimum value in an iterable. You can optionally provide a `key` function that is applied to the iterable before comparisons are made.

Here the iterable is a generator returning the numbers 0 to the length of the iterable `a`.

The key function applied to each element of the iterable takes the element and uses it to index into `a`. It then subtracts 11.5 from that value and takes the absolute value.

Overall what this does is return the index of the element of `a` which is nearest to 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to the following code, provided `a` contains at least one element:

```
def stupid_verbose_imperative_code():
    import math
    i = 0
    result = None
    min_key = math.inf
    while i < len(a):
        key = abs(a[i]-11.5)
        if key < min_key:
            min_key = key
            result = i
        i += 1
    return result
stupid_verbose_imperative_code()
```

as you can see, mastering python standard library greatly reduces needs to type code